# GoLang with go-swagger response headers

Tags: go, header, httpresponse, go-swagger

I am pretty new to golang and trying to set my response headers.  I have two headers that I want to set.  I think that I am misunderstanding something fundamental.  I am also using go-swagger to generate my endpoints.

My problem is that I can only seem to set one of my two headers.  Swagger provides a function "auth.NewAuthLoginUserOK().WithProfileHeader("pickles)" on the return (in the "if success" block).   How can I set two header params?

```
func AuthLoginRouteHandler(params auth.AuthLoginUserParams) middleware.Responder {
    transactionId := redFalconLogger.GetTransactionId()
    redFalconLogger.LogDebug("AuthLoginRouteHandler", transactionId)

    email := params.Body.Email
    password := params.Body.Password

    //Check to ensure that they are not nil
    if email == "" || password == ""{
        redFalconLogger.LogError("Got an empty string on a username/password", transactionId)
        return auth.NewAuthLoginUserBadRequest()
    }

    //use pointers to limit in flight private data
    pointerEmail := &email
    pointerPassword := &password

    //Call the auth domain
    success := authDomain.LoginUser(pointerEmail,pointerPassword,transactionId)

    if success {
        return auth.NewAuthLoginUserOK().WithProfileKeyHeader("pickles")
    }
    redFalconLogger.LogDebug("Failed Login: ", transactionId)
    return auth.NewAuthLoginUserBadRequest()
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go-swagger will generate one method per response header defined in the spec on result objects (what's returned by `auth.NewAuthLoginUserOK()`)

If you have multiple response headers defined in the spec you generated off of, just chain the calls.

```
return auth.NewAuthLoginUserOK().WithProfileKeyHeader("pickles").WithOtherHeader("cucumbers")
```

You should try and avoid deviating from the specification as much as possible. If you absolutely need to write a header not specified in the spec, the response object will have a ServeHTTP method you can use to get at the stdlib's ResponseWriter.

```
    return auth.NewAuthLoginUserOK().ServeHTTP(func(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // Try and avoid this
        rw.Header().Add("profile", "pickles")
        rw.Header().Add("other-header", "cucumbers")
    })
```

Comment: Thank you.   You are exactly right!!!    I forgot that i could "chain" them in golang.   Coming from a Java world I expected the method on the right to act on the response from the first.   

This was exactly the answer that I needed.

Also - I agree on not deviating from the spec but nice to see how it could be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below solution. Define like this in your swagger.yml

```
/deviceProvisioningDetails/{deviceId}:
    get:
      tags:
        - tenantManager
      operationId: getDeviceID
      parameters:
            - name: deviceId
              in: path
              description: Device ID
              required: true
              type: string
            - name: requestId
              in: header
              required: true
              description: "request id"
              type: string
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          headers:
            tenantId:
              type: string
              description: "Tenant Id"
```

Then in your configure.go you can return with payload.

```
  return tenant_manager.NewGetDeviceIDOK().WithTenantID(tenantId)
```